# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS without losing POST data

Tags: php, http, ssl, https

I am creating a shopping cart system, and I want the cart section to be complete secure via HTTPS, so for example the cart section could not be accessed by simply typing in

```
 http://example.com/cart/
```

If this occurs I want it to be redirected to https://example.com/cart/ but keep POST data if any.

Is this possible in either PHP or .htaccess?

Comment: Is this a good idea? Even if it is possible. Before the redirect all the data of the form will be submitted in the clear. Opening you up to an attack. Unless I've misunderstood.

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid, the cart itself is handled by sessions, but when I get to the payment section I want to make sure its form is sent under HTTPS if that makes any sense. Unless I should just let the form results die out on an attempt like that as it deter the attack?

Comment: yeah if your normal flow would already be submitting via https I would advise you just drop/reject anything that comes via http.

Comment: So is it possible to maybe via htaccess to specifically force http;//www.example.com/cart/ to https? SEO friendly

Comment: I figured it out;
   
    `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^cart https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: I guess you need to have a look at `hsts` technology, or find how to make internal(web server) redirect.